# How to server images and assets in nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I try to seperate backend from frontend.
The main location (http://localhost/) is the frontend folder.

The backend location (http://localhost/backend) is the backend folder.

This is how I handle the locations and folders in my configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    index  index.php index.html;

    location / {
        root   /html/frontend;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /frontend/index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location /backend/ {
      root /html/backend;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /backend/index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

The .php files are loaded as expected.
If I try to load an image in the index.php of http://localhost it shows a broken image.
This is the content of the index file:

```
<?php
echo 'public';
?>
<img src="test.png">
```

The image is located in the folder but it seems like there is an url issue.
Even if I try to load the image using the direct url it returns only the index.php (This is totally wrong).

The same issue happens when I try to load a stylesheet or a script.

Did I forget something in the configuration file?

Edit:
This is the public folder:
[image: public folder]

Comment: What are the correct URIs for your images and assets? The `src=` attribute value should begin with a `/` otherwise the browser will treat it as relative to whatever is currently being displayed in the address bar.

Comment: The absolute path is /html/frontend/350x150.png. But even this is showing as broken image. Usually I would use just src="350x150.png" since it's in the same directory as the index.php. Note: If I try to open image on localhost directly (http://localhost/html/frontend/350x150.png) it gives me the output of index.php, too.

Comment: I cannot see your `location ~ \.php$` block, but I assume it is using the default `root /html;` as your PHP URIs include the containing directory. If you access `/frontend/index.php` using the browser, the full URI for the image will be `/frontend/300x150.png`, which will be searched for at `/html/frontend/frontend/350x150.png` and not found.

Comment: Excuse me, I updated my question with the complete server block.  I tried to access http://localhost/frontend/index.php and the URI of the image is http://localhost/frontend/350x150.png - which give me exact the same output as index.php does.

Comment: Remove `root   /html/frontend;`

Comment: try renaming the image, adblock likes to block images which contain dimensions.

Comment: @RichardSmith this will return in 403 if anyone uses 'localhost' to access the public folder.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I renamed the image to 'test.png' which did not change anything.